# How to find a value in column and paste ranges from other worksheets into its adjacent columns

Tags: excel, vba

The end goal for my project is that the user will be able to select a value from a `ComboBox` to fill out a report on a Summary Tab. The report will consist of 3, 3 cell ranges (divided into 3 1x3 ranges on 3 separate worksheets).

I want to find the row with the value the user selected in the `ComboBox` and then set the 9 cells to the right of that value equal to the values in the range mentioned previously.

I've tried a couple of different ways of doing this, but I'll include the code I most recently worked on below:

```
Private Sub OKButton1_Click()
Dim userValue, rangeOne, rangeTwo, rangeThree
Dim i As Long

i = 4


userValue = ComboBox1.Value
Set rangeOne = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("F23:H23")
Set rangeTwo = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F90:H90")
Set rangeThree = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("F17:H17")



While Sheets("Reports").Range(cells(i,1)).Value <> "" 
      If Sheets("Reports").Range(cells(i, "A")).Value = "userValue" Then

         Set Sheets("Reports").Range(Cells(i, "B:E")) = rangeOne
         Set Sheets("Reports").Range(Cells(i, "F:I")) = rangeOne
         Set Sheets("Reports").Range(Cells(i, "J:M")) = rangeOne
      End If
      i = i + 1
Wend
Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

Any Ideas on how I can improve this or get it working? Currently getting 1004 errors.

Comment: work with `Range.Find method` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For x = 1 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), UserValue) > 0 Then
        ws1.Cells(x, 2) = ws2.Cells(23, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 3) = ws2.Cells(23, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 4) = ws2.Cells(23, 8).Value

        ws1.Cells(x, 6) = ws3.Cells(90, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 7) = ws3.Cells(90, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 8) = ws3.Cells(90, 8).Value

        ws1.Cells(x, 10) = ws4.Cells(18, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 11) = ws4.Cells(18, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 12) = ws4.Cells(18, 8).Value
    Else:
    End If
Next x
```

The above is what I'm working with now in place of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Two words of advice when working with excel:

1. **always** make variables for each sheet/book you need to work with
2. Avoid using ranges and objects if you can.  It is much easier to iterate over individual cells using an array and a for loop like I did below.

I was a bit confused on exactly what you needed done, so you will need to modify this slightly to fit your ranges/where you want the data to go.  If you are confused or need further assistance let me know and I'll update this.

```
Dim userValue
Dim xrow As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 as Worksheet, ws4 as Worksheet
Dim arrData() as variant

set ws1 = Worksheets("Report")
set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
set ws4 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

userValue = ComboBox1.Value
xrow = 1

ws2.activate
'the InStr function checks if the first condition contains the second, and when it does, it returns 1, which in turn triggers the if statement
for x = 1 To ws2.Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    if InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), userValue) > 0 Then
        arrData(0) = ws2.Cells(x, 2).value
        arrData(1) = ws2.Cells(x, 3).value
        arrData(2) = ws2.Cells(x, 4).value
    else:
    end if
next x

ws3.activate
for x = 1 To ws3.Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    if InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), userValue) > 0 Then
        arrData(3) = ws3.Cells(x, 2).value
        arrData(4) = ws3.Cells(x, 3).value
        arrData(5) = ws3.Cells(x, 4).value
    else:
    end if
next x

ws4.activate
for x = 1 To ws4.Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    if InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), userValue) > 0 Then
        arrData(6) = ws4.Cells(x, 2).value
        arrData(7) = ws4.Cells(x, 3).value
        arrData(8) = ws4.Cells(x, 4).value
    else:
    end if
next x

ws1.activate
ws1.Cells(xrow, 1) = userValue
for y = 0 To 8
    ws1.Cells(xrow, y+1).value = arrData(y)
next y
xrow = xrow + 1
```

Comment: Sorry, just now realizing how confusing my original wording is. Essentially there are four worksheets, on three worksheets are tables that have three columns summed in three individual cells. One a fourth worksheet I have a summary tab where I've got a ComboBox which has options made up of entries on the first column of the fourth sheet (dynamic, so options will be added in as the user adds them).

I want the user to be able to select one of entries, and then have the three cells from each of the worksheets copy over to 9 of the cells to the right of that entry.

Comment: I added an response to this question with an updated loop, while its functional now I don't seem to be getting the right values.EDIT: I got it to work! Thanks for your insight, it helped me figure out what I was getting wrong. Boy was I over thinking this.